# Facebook Share OG tags not recognized

Tags: html, meta-tags

I am trying to setup the following page for sharing to Facebook:

https://infinitec.caxy.com/user-badge/65aef1eb3795a13d9ee8f26b

I have  tags for the following:

```
  <meta property='og:url' content='https://infinitec.caxy.com/user-badge/65aef1eb3795a13d9ee8f26b' />
  <meta property='og:type' content='profile' />
  <meta property='og:title' content='Infinitec Learning Badge Earned!' />
  <meta property='og:description' content='Caxy Superadmin' />
  <meta property='og:image' content='https://infinitec-qa-certificates.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/InfLearningTemplate/documents/659c427a397970c0737a817e/fc53707e-fe2d-49ac-ad23-b8a6a9af75c3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAUDQGYL6D54IMKWUY&Expires=1706207009&Signature=Dr5%2FbW%2BBvj5rVMimw5RXucl2HUU%3D' />
```

On the link itself youll be able to observe that the meta tags are in the html head...

But you will notice that even the sharing debugger is not recognizing any of these:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Finfinitec.caxy.com%2Fuser-badge%2F65aef1eb3795a13d9ee8f26b

I have pressed "scrape again" several times.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?